# Подсчёт символов в строке

Tags: c++, строки

У меня меня есть строка, в которой могут быть символы как английского, так и русского алфавитов, и мне не вполне понятно, как посчитать в такой строке количество символов.

```
string test = "ТестTest";
cout << test.length();
```

Как известно, в потоке выхода мы получим не количество символов, а количество байт, то есть не 8, а 12.
А хотелось бы как-то узнать именно количество символов. Какое решение проблемы в данном ситуации будет правильным?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой вариант - использовать более широкие строки, чтобы символ помещался в один элемент. Пример:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::wstring test = L"ТестTest";
    std::wcout << test.length();
}
```

[Вывод](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0Y0q2jM57AfDZYfI):

> ```
> 8
> ```

Более правильный вариант - использовать соответствующие внешние библиотеки для поддержки *Unicode*, например, [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).